# How do I make that a cut object in MS Publisher pastes on the exact same location it came from?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

I am switching an object between Master Page and a page itself for making a poster; I put it on the master page if I think it is fine and I don't want to be able anymore to move it.

At first, when I cut it from a page and put it on the Master Page, it was placed at exactly the same location it came from, which is quite useful. Now, "all of the sudden" (I have no idea what I could have changed meanwhile), when I paste it on the Master Page, it comes on a random (but deterministic) spot; as if the Master Page "paste area" is shifted w.r.t. the normal page.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!